# Definition of homomorphism between multigraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

My professor is using this definition for a multigraph and a homomorphism between multigraphs:

> A multigraph consists of two sets, $V\ne \{\emptyset\}$ and $E$, and a set-theoretic map $\phi:E\to V^{[2]}$, where $V^{[n]}$ denotes the set of the subsets of $V$ with cardinality $n$.

> A homomorphism of multigraphs, say $(V,E,\phi)$ and $(V',E',\phi')$, consists of a couple of maps, $\alpha :V\to V'$ and $\beta :E\to E'$, such that the inclusion $\phi ' (\beta (e))\subseteq\alpha (\phi(e))$ holds for any $e\in E$. A homomorphism is a isomorphism if $\phi ' (\beta (e))=\alpha (\phi(e))$.

Now, I'm not sure to understand this definition: for example, I don't understand why the isomorphisms are defined like that. If I have the multigraph $(V,E,\phi)$, with two edges ($e_1,e_2$) connecting the vertex $v_1 $ and $v_2$, and I consider the same multigraph but with only an edge between $v_1 $ and $v_2$, ($e$), it seems to me that the equality in the definition of isomorphism is satisfied, even if these two multigraphs are not isomorphic. (The homomorphism would consist of the identities between the sets of vertex and the sets of edges, except for $e_1$ and $e_2$ both mapped in $e$). Where I am contradicting? Thanks for the help

Comment: The definition of an isomorphism is incomplete, as far as I can tell: it should require that the maps $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are bijections. (Really it should just require an inverse.)

Comment: For any $e\in E$ the set $\varphi'(\beta(e))$ is a $2$-element subset of $V'$, and so is the set $\alpha[\varphi(e)]$, so if one is a subset of the other, they are automatically equal.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott the map $\alpha$ is not necessarily injective, so $\phi '( \beta (e))$ and $\alpha (\phi (e))$ could actually be a single element of $V'$. However if one is a single element the other is a single element too, so I don't even see a homomorphism for which the inclusion in the definition holds and the equality doesn't.

Comment: @Dorian: But $\varphi'(\beta(e))$ is by definition a $2$-element set, so it cannot be a subset of $\alpha[\varphi(e)]$ unless the latter is also a doubleton.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So you too think that, with this definition, the inclusion always implies the equality between $\phi '( \beta (e))$ and $\alpha (\phi(e))$, right?

Comment: @Dorian: Yes, I do. And I also agree with Qiaochu Yuan.